# Make cURL Connect through a Proxy to HTTPS

Tags: php

I have the following code and was wondering how I would make the following cURL connection go through a proxy in the format "1.1.1.1:80"

I have tried the following, but even with an invalid proxy the connection still seems to work meaning it must have not gone through the proxy.

Thank you for the help!

```
    function checkPlayer($player, $user_sess) {
$resultx = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM proxy
WHERE username='$user_sess' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1");
$rowx = mysql_fetch_array($resultx);
$proxy = $rowx['proxy'];
echo "$proxy  Result - ";
ob_flush();
flush();
$mcURL = 'https://www.minecraft.net/haspaid.jsp?user=';
$mcURL = $mcURL.$player;
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $mcURL);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); //Add this
$auth = curl_exec($curl);
   if (trim($auth) == "true") {
        echo "Premium<BR>";
ob_flush();
flush();
    }
    else {
    echo "Not Premium<BR>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That didn't work because **`$proxy`** variable is not accessible inside your function.

Add it inside like this

```
function checkPlayer($player) {
$proxy = "1.1.1.1:80"; //<--- Here
```

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the post with the new method.

Now if the proxy is not working the result is not premium, which is good but how do I make it so if the proxy isn't working then it states the proxy is not working rather than Not Premium

TY For help sir, you are amazing!

Comment: Also, if that can not be done no worries. A major issue with my code is that when that script is running to see if users are premium no other pages on my webserver can load.

Comment: Just add an `exit;` statement after `echo "Not Premium<BR>";` so it won't load content after that.

Comment: Well it needs to check multiple players, here I'll show you what I mean. The whole webserver crashes for some reason while that script is running and once it completes, the webserver comes back online.

Here is a livestream of the problem: http://www.twitch.tv/missiontech